# How can I replace a picture in php with a link to a picture?

Tags: php, hyperlink, imgur

I have the following line of code:

```
<body style="background: url('img/start-bg.png'); background-size: cover; background-attachment: fixed;">

<div class="col-sm-4"><img src="img/3.png"></div>
```

I want to replace the start-bg.png with an imgur link, what do I need to do?

Comment: Delete that text and put in the imgur text(link)? There is no PHP here.

Comment: I dont want to have the picture local stored on my server, I want to post a link of the picture.

Comment: can you tell me an example where exactly I should put in the link?

Comment: This is "HTML 101" stuff.

Comment: Replace `img/start-bg.png` with the imgur link.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body style="background: url('https://i.imgur.com/MAa7BF9.jpg')">
```

Just find a image in imgur, right click, open image in a new tab and put the link as url.
(the example above works fine)